# ASP.NET C# json data from string using regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want get Below picture json data sender>id:"value" and message>text: "value"

just get value string

use asp.net c# Text.RegularExpressions, how can i do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeR1O.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [Newtonsoft.JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) instead of trying to parse it with Regex.

It is as easy to use as this example from the website:

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
// Bad Boys
```